# How to verify a backup file from ADB backup

Tags: backup

I have backed up my phone via adb to my computer by doing the command:

```
adb backup -all -apk -f C:\myfolder\backup.ab
```

I went to look at the file it had created when it said the backup was finished, but it says it is 0 bytes big.

Is this because of the encryption? I am worrying if my phone is backed up properly...

Comment: If it's zero bytes, it's definitely not backed up properly. Encryption can't make an empty file store data!

Comment: Question might sound stupid, but anyway: After executing that command, did you confirm the backup *on your Android device*? Otherwise, there would be no data send to the PC, and the `adb backup` command would simply "time out" – resulting in an empty backup, possibly.

Comment: @Izzy How long would the time out take? On my device it said "Backup Finished" just a second after it said "Backup Started".

Comment: That's much too fast for a timeout. I didn't check, but expect it to be at least 10 seconds. Maybe you check your logs (`adb logcat`) to see if they reveal something?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there was a bug in the Samsung OS that corrupted the desktop backup password.

One day, my phone bootlooped and, after a reset, I could backup fine with no backup password set.