# How to verify an ADB backup file is complete and in a good state?

Tags: adb, backup

This is not a duplicate of [How to verify a backup file from ADB backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61689/how-to-verify-a-backup-file-from-adb-backup). The poster there probably didn't know that an unrooted phone requires `-nosystem` ([ref](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29635/how-do-i-know-when-adb-backup-is-finished?)) and ended with a 0 byte file, where my backup file is almost 8GB.

Given that adb gives almost zero feedback on it's backup progress and success or failure. How can I be confident that [the backup I've just completed](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82512/46758) is a good one? and that it contains what I think it does? and that it will (probably) work to restore or extract data from?

I have the one android device (Nexus 5), access to Win7 PCs, and ubuntu virtual machines if needed.

Comment: Though not directly related to your question, this does answer it in a very round-about way. I found this blog which gives directions on how to open the file and modify contents. My reasoning is that if the file opens then it should *probably* be ok.<br>
Here's the link: http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html<br>
I'd really love if anyone finds a more straight forward foolproof approach and post it here.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux, [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) contains a tiny little shell script to convert ADB Backups (`.ab`) to tar files, which you then easily can investigate with any archive manager. Only limitation is: it doesn't work on password protected backup files.

The basic command it runs (everything else mainly is a wrapper for command line options and syntax) is:

```
dd if=$1 bs=24 skip=1 | openssl zlib -d >${1%%.ab}.tar && gzip -9 ${1%%.ab}.tar
```

A command I've found here on SE some time in the past (full disclosure: I'm the author of *Adebar*) – [see here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77376/16575).

As you can see in the quoted command, it requires `openssl` and `zlib` to be available.

Comment: note: On Ubuntu, the 'openssl zlib -d' will give you an error message. You can use 'zlib-flate -uncompress' instead.

Comment: Umm? I use it that way on Ubuntu. Adebar is being developed/tested on Ubuntu even. But it's always good to have alternatives, so thanks for the note, @jellefoks!

Answer (score 2):

For unencrypted backups, it is possible to list the content using the command

```
dd if=backup-file2.ab bs=24 skip=1 | pigz -d | tar -tvf - > backup-file.ab.list
```